# Image not found or type unknown Dompdf 0.8.1 and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I want to load an image to PDF from generated image.

I had set **isRemoteEnabled to true** and 
generated QRCode working fine

Here is my code.

```
$this->load->library(array('pdf', 'ciqrcode'));

$data = array('qrlink' => base_url('generateQR?text=123'));
$this->pdf->set_paper('folio');
$this->pdf->loadHtml($this->load->view('pdfoutput', $data, true));
$this->pdf->set_base_path(base_url());
$this->pdf->render();
$this->pdf->stream('QR-PDF', array("Attachment" => false));
```

And here is my view

```
<img src="<?= $qrlink ?>" alt="QRcode" width="150px">
```

But the output say **Image not found or type unknown**.
So what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: `echo $qrlink` and post output

Comment: intra.mydomain.go.id/generateQR?text=123 Note : server intranet. its working fine in localhost, but not working on server @DeadManAlive

Comment: this is not proper `intra.mydomain.go.id/generateQR?text=123` image file extention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue and after many hours searching the inter-web, I found out (thanks to [Atiruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491512/atiruz) ) that **Dompdf** does **NOT** render images well with remote urls e.g. *http://your-domain.com/com/images/img.png" />* always gave me the same error [Image not found or type unknown]. In my case***strong text*** I had to use a base64 encoded image and it seemed to have resolved my issue.

I wrote a small snippet that can encode your image into base64 and return a string to use inside your  tag.

Here is how to use the base64 encode data as your img src

```
//Use a valid base64 encoded data string
<img src="your-base64-encoded-image-string" />
```

Here is the snippet to convert your image into a base64 encoded image data

```
function encode_img_base64( $img_path = false, $img_type = 'png' ){
    if( $img_path ){
        //convert image into Binary data
        $img_data = fopen ( $img_path, 'rb' );
        $img_size = filesize ( $img_path );
        $binary_image = fread ( $img_data, $img_size );
        fclose ( $img_data );

        //Build the src string to place inside your img tag
        $img_src = "data:image/".$img_type.";base64,".str_replace ("\n", "", base64_encode($binary_image));

        return $img_src;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with pdf and i solved using this function

```
function encode_img_base64($img_path = false): string
{
    if($img_path){
        $path = $img_path;
        $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        return 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for all the boiler code. DomPDF recognises image's full public url. Simply just link the image as `https://www.domain_name.com/images/image_name.png` and you'll be fine