# Laravel Dompdf Image not found or type unknown

Tags: image, laravel-5, dompdf

I'm trying to get the user image in our application when downloading pdf, my problem now is that the uploaded images will display `Image not found or type unknown`. Tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690599/laravel-dompdf-error-image-not-found-or-type-unknown), but got no luck. My image url is in full path like `http://localhost/storage/app/public/pic/user_pic/82ac9404bdb74d0ad980a30faadeab22cd41b38d.jpg`. I also tried doing it this way : 
`<td><img src="{{ public_path("storage/pic/user_pic/". basename($data->pic_path)) }}" style="height:200px; width:300px"><td>`, and still no luck. Here's my full code in downloading the pdf:

**Controller**

```
$users = $this->userListService->getUserDataPDF($request);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.user_pdf', compact('guests'))->setPaper('','landscape');
$pdf->getDomPDF()->setHttpContext(
    stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed'=> TRUE,
            'verify_peer' => FALSE,
            'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
        ]
    ])
);

return $pdf->download(Carbon::now()->format('Ymd') . 'user.pdf',compact('users','pdf'));
```

**view**

```
<tr>
    <td><img src="{{$users->pic_path}}" style="height:200px; width:300px"></td>
</tr>
```

Someone has an idea on this?

Comment: Someone has any idea on this please? Thank you.

Comment: What's in `$users->pic_path` ? Path or url? I think Dompdf requires the url to work.

Comment: @Sir_Faenor It's a server path since it is uploaded in our system. http://localhost/storage/app/public/pic/user_pic/82ac9404bdb74d0ad980a30faadeab22cd41b38d.jpg

Comment: Can you convert it to a relative url? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51262085/1095913

Comment: @Sir_Faenor Tried it, but I have error: `fopen(http://localhost/storage/app/public/pic/user_pic/82ac9404bdb74d0ad980a30faadeab22cd41b38d.jpg): failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: You can use alternatively a relative url or an encoded source for the `<img>`. If you choose the encoded one, try to pass a path to `fopen`, not an url.

Comment: @Sir_Faenor You mean use the server path?

Comment: @Sir_Faenor It works now. Thanks for the assistance . You're such a great help. Upvoted the answer link you've given me.

Answer (score 0):

As you use File Storage system in Laravel, you use

```
php artisan storage:link
```

to access to a readable/writable path. In my case:

```
storage -> /var/www/mysite.com/storage/app/public
```

So I use

```
<img src="{{ public_path().'/storage/logo-1.png' }}">
```

This implies that my logo is located in

```
/var/www/mysite.com/storage/app/public/logo-1.png
```

In your case:

```
<img src="{{ public_path().'/storage/pic/user_pic/82ac9404bdb74d0ad980a30faadeab22cd41b38d.jpg' }}">
```

I hope this help you!